# FFmpeg PNG overlayed on background image to video

Tags: ffmpeg, png, overlay

I'm trying to overlay an image on a background image and make a video from it with a certain duration.

I found something on some old 2011 thread but FFmpeg doesn't seem to find '-loop_input' so I guess it's an outdated command.

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -vframes 250 -an -vcodec png test.mov
```

How do I make this work in the current ffmpeg version?

Comment: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production" -- these questions are off-topic for [SO] and should be asked somewhere else

Comment: @talonmies How is this not programmatic? I was clearly asking about a feature not about an "interactive use of the command line tool"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-loop` option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -frames:v 250 -c:v png test.mov
```

But because you are going from PNG to PNG you can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -frames:v 250 -c:v copy test2.mov
```

- Default frame rate is 25, so I removed the `-r 25`. If you want to set frame rate with image inputs then use the image demuxer `-framerate` input option, such as `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i background.png ...`
- Your input has no audio, so I removed `-an`.
- `-f image2` is not needed: it will automatically determine the proper demuxer.